# Dynamics 365 Human Resource integration with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-365, power-automate

I am working on **Dynamics 365 Human Resource** implementation. Organization is using Office 365/Azure AD for internal user accounts. The requirement is to connect Azure AD with D365 HR in a way that whenever a new user is created in Active Directory the same user should also be created in D365 HR Users list. This should be done automatically. The objective here is to avoid manual user creation in D365 Apps.

Initially, I thought about achieving this with **MS Flow** with below approach:

1. Using Azure AD connector get list of Users in certain Group.
2. Using CDS connector get list of all Users in Dynamics.
3. Create new User(s) in CDS/Dynamics HR.

I have the basic understanding that D365 HR uses CDS to store all data but I can't seem to find D365 HR specific **Users** entity. Hence this approach fails.

So, my question is how to achieve such automatic integration?

I am open to custom development options but can't manage to think of a viable solution. Please share ideas! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD is Microsoft's cloud-based identity and access management service. It is intended for app developers and Microsoft 365, Azure, or Dynamics 365 subscribers. So, each Dynamics 365 tenant is automatically an Azure AD tenant.

Kindly go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/human-resources/hr-developer-api-authentication) and check whether if it helps .

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_6EbQ6KllpWo3Jul&Q_CHL=gl
>

Answer (score 0):

HR users and security aren't stored in the CDS today. There are ISV products that support the creation of a D365 HR user account (and automatic assignment of D365 security roles by policy) if you're interested in going this route:

- http://www.elevate-hr.com/solutions/#_active-directory-integration
- https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations/elevate-hr.active-directory-integration?tab=Overview

Answer (score 0):

Someone having a similar question in 2023, might find this useful. Microsoft recently released a new preview capability called API-driven provisioning which now makes it possible to implement HR-driven provisioning from any system of record.

To learn more about this capability, refer: [API-driven inbound provisioning concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/inbound-provisioning-api-concepts)

For sample PowerShell scripts / Logic Apps workflows, refer: 
* [PowerShell based integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/inbound-provisioning-api-powershell) 
* [Azure Logic Apps based integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/inbound-provisioning-api-logic-apps)

For Dynamics365/HR integration, use the Logic Apps [Dataverse connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connect-common-data-service) to read data from [Dataverse tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/human-resources/hr-developer-entities) and then tweak the sample Logic Apps module per your requirement.

The primary advantage of using this approach is that the Azure AD provisioning service does all the heavy lifting of comparing what data has changed and applying the change, so your script doesn't need to implement the AD user fetch + comparison logic. Just regularly upload the data you get from your HR to the provisioning [/bulkUpload API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-post-bulkupload?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and your good to go.